# Resize images to store in drawable folder

Tags: android

I'm having some troubles with display of images, someone can help me?
- I've a listView and I wanna show one different image in each item of this list (in background), all right, my images has the resolution so much large (for example 6016x2188px), then I have to resize them, by:

```
public static int getInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options opt, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final int imgWidth = opt.outWidth;//rec a larg orig da img
        final int imgHeight = opt.outHeight;//rec a alt orig da img
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        LogUtil.logD(LogUtil.LOG_TAG, "Img Alt -> %s | Img Larg -> %s", String.valueOf(imgHeight), String.valueOf(imgWidth));

        if (imgWidth > reqWidth || imgHeight > reqHeight) {
            final int halfHeight = imgHeight / 2;
            final int halfWidth = imgWidth / 2;

            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight &&
                    (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {

                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }

            long totalPixels = imgWidth * imgHeight / inSampleSize;

            final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
                totalPixels /= 2;
            }
        }

        LogUtil.logD(LogUtil.LOG_TAG, "Img inSampleSize -> %s", String.valueOf(inSampleSize));
        return inSampleSize;
    }


public static Bitmap getSampleBitmap(Context ctx, int imgId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        Resources res = ctx.getResources();

        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, imgId, opt);

        opt.inSampleSize = getInSampleSize(opt, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        LogUtil.logD(LogUtil.LOG_TAG, "Decode bitmap...");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, imgId, opt);
    }

//each row in adapter
txtview.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), getSampleBitmap(ctx, R.drawable.img, txtview.getWidth(), txtview.getHeight())));
```

Ok, it works, but my app is displaying this images with a time gap, and this makes the app very strange.

Then some people had said that I have to store the images already resized in drawable folder, but how I'll know how many pixels I have to resize if the android deals with dp and this dp can become different amount of pixel depending on of resolution of each device? (I wanna store just a xxdpi to that the app do not be so many large)

If I resize them to 800px of width (the best quality for tablets 10"), this will work properly to all other resolution?

By the way, the .setBackgroundDrawable() is deprecated, so any other idea to set a bitmap like background?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this asset studio to generate the complete set of properly sized images organized into the correct Drawable folders.  After generation, you just download the zip, extract the folders and place them in your app hierarchy.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example

Comment: Hi. Actually, I meant the others images but icons. Like backgrounds for example. But thanks any way.